# Is it Possible to force a Discriminator While using the Joined Inheritance Strategy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, jakarta-ee

For the sake of my Database Administrator I had to use a Joined Inheritance Strategy, this would be easier to use Single.Table but eh, so let's Say an entity :

```
@Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public abstract class Post{
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            protected Long id;
            protected String title;
            protected String d_type;// I want this to to be the discriminator.
}
```

And the child :

```
    @Entity
    public abstract class Book{
            protected String title;
}
```

The Example is simple for the sake of a good answer, but In reality I am dealing with 5 "children" each of those have its specific attributes and methods except one let's call it `CommonPost` which adds nothing to what the parent already provides, that why I want to add a discriminator with an enum type as follows {xPost,yPost,..,CommonPost}. First is it possible or even practical?If not what better options would be practical.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you can check with your JPA vendor if it is supported. I believe Hibernate supports this. They call it Mixed Inheritance strategy:

Here's a sample:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="POST_TYPE")
public abstract class Post{
```

Technically, it is a JOINED strategy but nothing prevents you from adding a discriminator column (which is commonly used for SINGLE-TABLE strategy).

Also another suggestion: If you say that entity `CommonPost` does not have any specific properties or methods, then why not make it the top-most class in your inheritance hierarchy? Then you can now eliminate the abstract class `Post`.

Here's how you may do it:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="POST_TYPE")
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class CommonPost {
...
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
public class XPost extends CommonPost {
...
@DiscriminatorValue("Y")
public class YPost extends CommonPost {
```